# Swagger Java date format validation throws exception

Tags: java, spring, swagger

Please help me to resolve the issue related to the swagger validation because same regex is working in java but fails in swagger.

Working java Code:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    String regex = "^((19|20)\\d\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";
    Assert.assertTrue("Date: matched.", Pattern.matches(regex, "19881231")); -- true
}
```

Swagger Contract.yml

```
properties:
  lineofValue:
    type: string
    pattern: ^AB|CD$
    description:  mandatory
  date:
    type: string
    pattern: ^((19|20)\\d\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
    description:  mandatory
```

Sample Req:

```
{
"lineofValue":"AB"
"date":"19881231"
}
```

Exception :

```
{
   "code": "400",
   "status": 400,
   "message": "Validation Failed: ECMA 262 regex \"^((19|20)\\\\d\\\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$\" does not match input string \"19881231\""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through the [`Swagger Documentation`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/), it appears that you *do not* need to escape the `/` character in the same way that you need to do in Java:

```
properties:
  lineofValue:
    type: string
    pattern: ^AB|CD$
    description:  mandatory
  date:
    type: string
    pattern: ^((19|20)\d\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
    description:  mandatory
```

Comment: Thanks npinti for your answer